# Add a new tag based on the category name in the publish event

Tags: plugin-development, categories, tags

As you can see in this action, it is overwriting all existing tags by catname, how to add a new tag, preserving the current tags, and not only in update but in publish event, since I use an import plugin, And currently I have to enter all posts and click on update to take the desired action.

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post', 'add_cat_to_tags', 10, 3 );
function add_cat_to_tags( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
   $tags = array();
   $cats = get_the_category( $post_ID );
   foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
      $tags[] .= $cat->name;
   }
   // overwrites any existing tags!!
   wp_set_post_tags( $post_ID, $tags );
}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `true` parameter to the [`wp_set_post_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_tags) function. Tested and works, the corrected code:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post', 'add_cat_to_tags', 10, 3 );
function add_cat_to_tags( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
   $tags = array();
   $cats = get_the_category( $post_ID );
   foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
      $tags[] .= $cat->name;
   }
   // overwrites any existing tags!!
   wp_set_post_tags( $post_ID, $tags, true );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ciaik for reply, yes, this solution is to preserve existing tags, but before, I already had one that worked even without me understanding why! Adding within forech $post_content [] = $cat-> name; And too add parameter $post_ID, $tags, $post_content !! I confess that I do not understand, but it always worked! What I really need, what I really need is the other request, but it only works on manual posts, I need this to happen when the plugin auto posts, auto import, and I having to go into the post and click publish/update for the tags to be add!